# Proper way to have multiple installs with a single database

Tags: wp-config, site-url

Here's my scenario:

I have a development zone with a standard WordPress installation (dev.domain.com/project). When it comes time to showing work to clients, I use version control to copy the dev installation to a beta zone (beta.domain.com/project). So, a pretty standard setup. They share the same database.

However, using this method in wp-config.php on the beta zone to change the site and home URL doesn't work:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://beta.domain.com/project');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://beta.domain.com/project');
```

Because it alters the value in the database, meaning that when I go to load the dev zone, it now redirects to the beta zone. This is what happens for pretty much all methods described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

So, what is the proper way to have two separate installations with different URL's share the same database? I know of the WP DB Migrate plugin, which I've already used, but in this case I want the databases to be shared.

Comment: I can't imagine why do u need to share one db between 2 web.. if you'll be able to acomplish your goal, then on editing something on eny of 2 installs, u'll change on seccond web.. so u can't setup different themes, activate different plugins.. there's no use in seccond website. Search engins will doungrade your rating becouse of dublicate content.. So what posible reason is to do 2 websites with single database ?
But if u need to be able to change only few tables ( like wp_posts and wp_postmeta ) you can do it by rewriting them in `posts_where`, with `$table_prefix = 'wp_';` different..

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I posted this before doing a proper investigation.

The issue isn't with WordPress, it was instead with how Polylang (translation plugin) handled the site url. The solution was to put `define('PLL_CACHE_HOME_URL', false);` in the wp-config.php before I changed the URL using the WP constants.